# Android N InvalidKeyException

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat, javax.crypto

I have an app that is still targeting Android 6.0, but am getting cryptography errors when trying to install on Android N (I've tried targeting N, too). Here is the stacktrace:

```
W/System.err: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Algorithm requires a PBE key
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(BaseBlockCipher.java:564)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(BaseBlockCipher.java:1006)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2977)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2884)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2789)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:956)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1199)
W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1143)
```

As you can see, it occurs when calling Cipher.init. Here is my aesDecrypt method:

```
public static String aesDecrypt(String data, String password) {
    try {
        String aesKey = getAesKey(password);
        byte[] keyValue = Base64.decode(aesKey, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] dataB = Base64.decode(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        byte[] decVal = c.doFinal(dataB);
        return new String(decVal);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And my getAesKey:

```
private static String getAesKey(String password) {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return Base64.encodeToString(hash, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have verified that the key I'm passing in c.init is not null.
Why would this not work on a phone running 7.0?

---

[EDIT from comments]

The code above uses:

```
 AES_ALGO = "PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you haven't shown us is the value of `AES_ALGO` and this is likely to indicate PBE encryption, which the key is not generated using any kind of PBE key derivation (such as PBKDF1 or PBKDF2). Those keys will return a different type of key algorithm than just `"AES"`.

Apparently there is a difference between various versions of Android in this respect. That would not be the first time that there is a usage difference within the Android providers, as they change implementation rather regularly. The API is still identical but the implementation of the algorithms differs somewhat.

To encrypt using CBC mode encryption - as used by the PBE encryption method - please take a look at the countless examples of using `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`. Don't forget that you need to handle the IV value correctly, something that is included in the Bouncy Castle PBE cipher itself.

---

[EDIT]

To my surprise the PBE key that is "calculated" by BC simply contains the password and iteration count of the PBE spec. Only util utilized with the cipher is the value calculated. The type of the key is not just `SecretKey` but:

> org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BCPBEKey

It also contains placeholders for e.g. the IV value. So it's no surprise that the calculation doesn't currently work at all. What's more surprising is that it seems to have worked before.

Moral of the story, don't mix Ciphers and SecretKeys willy-nilly. It may work for specific versions, but the code may crap out when the developers decide to perform more stringent checking.

I tried simply using the name of the PBE algorithm for the key, but obviously that can never work.

Comment: AES_ALGO = "PBEWITHSHA256AND128BITAES-CBC-BC." It appears to be using BouncyCastle on all versions.

Comment: @9erNumber16 Why not just rewrite it to "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"? That should do the same thing, and should be true to what you're trying to do. PBE requires key derivation (PBKDF1 or 2), and you're doing that yourself (badly of course for weak passwords, but still).

Comment: That said, you may need to handle the IV value as well.